# best practice for C++ inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

If I want to use inheritance to avoid repeating the `common_method` method below

```
int A::different_method()
{ return 1; }

int A::common_method()
{ return this->different_method()+1; }

int B::different_method()
{ return 2; }

int B::common_method()
{ return this->different_method()+1; }
```

what is the best way to do it?

One way is to make `A` and `B` inherit from a base class `C`, with the new methods:

```
int A::different_method()
{ return 1; }

int B::different_method()
{ return 2; }

int C::different_method()
{ return 0; }

int C::common_method()
{ return this->different_method()+1; }
```

but it is a little bit annoying that I have to also define the useless `C::different_method`. What is the best practice for such situations?

Comment: not 100% sure what you are asking, but have a look at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54c71d7ddaa147fe

Comment: The purpose of inheritance isn't really about avoiding repetition of functions.   The purpose is relating types of objects in a logical way (e.g. public inheritance can represent "is-a" relationships like "a labrador is a dog", and private inheritance can represent "implemented in terms of" relationships like "a widget is implemented as a graphical component").   Doing that can, as a consequence, reduce repetition of code.   But *starting* with a goal of reducing repetition tends to result in strangely connected categories of object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [pure virtual function](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/virtual-functions#pure-virtual):

```cpp
struct Base {
    virtual int different_method() = 0;

    int common_method() {
        return different_method() + 1;
    } 
};

struct Derived1 : Base {
    int different_method() override {
        return 1;
    }
};

struct Derived2 : Base {
    int different_method() override {
        return 2;
    }
};
```

Check it out [live](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tLgA5SW9ABk8tTADljAI0zEuATlIAHVAsLqtHqGJuY%2BfgF0tvZORq7unF5KKmp0DATMxATBxqacFsmYqoHpmQTRji5unooZWTmh%2BbVlFbHxngCUiqgGxMgcAORSAMx2yIZYANTiwzrqCgTEmMxGM9jiAAwAgptbC8QGqpPSzErTAOyy25M3kwBueFkGbJN2BJP4VFRuWgQA%2BkZMAQEBgIB1psMACKTDYzK47a63N6TNBGIx0AFAkHoMEXeG3AmTJYEXq0D54L4/eiY4Gg8FySacOG7Anic7Q3ZsyHM7a7faHd6Qtx4O6YdCcSYgY6nTB4llI%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%2Bla1o237T0UXbrxHccQHW6c11rSRxs4WseGGNcNiar7hh%2BvCTzh/GvskRmj2Zvb4a6bV/A0bggA%3D%3D)

Comment: Prefer `override` over `virtual` to indicate overridden methods. compiler might help to spot "typos" in that case.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks. I appreciate your suggestion. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> One way is to make A and B inherit from a base class C,

Yes, you would need a base `class C`

```
class C {
public:
  virtual ~C() { }

  virtual int different_method() = 0;

  virtual int C::common_method() { 
     return this->different_method()+1; 
  }

}

class A: public C {
   // Implement 
   int different_method() override;
};

class B: public C {
   int different_method() override;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to use the class A and B, you can declare your C class as abstract and implement only the `common_method()`. The `different_method()` can be declared in header file of C class as ***pure virtual function*** in this way:

```
virtual different_method()=0
```

I leave you a useful link for the [pure virtual function and the abstract class](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Classes/Abstract_Classes)

Answer (score 0):

Are you really tied to the `A a; a.common_method()` syntax?

Why not

```
template <typename T>
int common_free_function(T& t) {
    return t.different_method() + 1;
}

A a;
B b;
common_free_function(a);
common_free_function(b);
```